# Doctrine 2.1 - how to check generated SQL

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Could someone tell me what I must do to see generated SQL by `createQuery()`?

Comment: For debugging, it's better to set up a logger: `$config->setSQLLogger(new Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$myQuery = $em->createQuery('SELECT v FROM ....... v');
$myQuery->getSQL();
```

$myQuery->getSQL(); would return the query for you. See docs here

[QUERY METHODS](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/api)

Comment: The link is now broken; maybe it was pointing to the [Class Query](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/class-Doctrine.ORM.Query.html) page?